# Summation: Evaluate $\sum_0^{n-1} \left[ x + \frac r n \right]$, $[\cdot]$ = greatest integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

$$\sum_0^{n-1} \left[ x + \frac r n \right], \space [\cdot] \equiv \text{greatest integer}$$

The answer as mentioned in the answer key is $[nx]$, but I am unable to understand. The summation opens up to give:
$$\left[ x \right] + \left[ x + \frac 1 n \right] + \left[ x + \frac 2 n \right] + \left[ x + \frac 3 n \right] + \space ...$$
Now, depending on the value of x and n, the value can be $n[x]$, $[x] + (n-1)([x]+1)$, $2[x] + (n-2)([x]+1)$ or anything of the above sort. How is the solution $[nx]$, with the 'n' inside the greatest integer function?

Comment: I think the answer lies in figuring out exactly how many of the terms are equal to $[x]$, and how many of them are equal to $[x]+1$, depending on $x$ and $n$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_identity

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you post as an answer so that I can accept it?